# C# Winforms Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

Summary: My application starts off with a license validation form and if the client's license is valid. It should launch the main form.

However I am receiving the following error: Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.

My implementation:

```
static class Program
{
    static AppStartUp appStartUp_;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        appStartUp_ = new AppStartUp();
        appStartUp_.OnValidationSuccessful += OnValidationSuccessful;

        Application.Run(appStartUp_);
    }

    static void OnValidationSuccessful()
    {
        appStartUp_.OnValidationSuccessful -= OnValidationSuccessful;
        appStartUp_.Close();
        appStartUp_.Dispose();

        //Application.ExitThread();
        Application.Run(new Manager());
    }
}
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should only call `Application.Run` once during your program's lifetime. Use `Show` or `ShowDialog` on the `Manager` instead.

Comment: @Cameron I already tried that but it does not work because upon disposing/closing the first form, Manager form does not even open. Program lifetime ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first Application.Run is still running during that OnValidationSuccessful event.  Assuming that event is closing the form, try setting a variable instead:

```
static bool appOK = false;
```

then in your event, set it to true:

```
static void OnValidationSuccessful()
{
  appOK = true;
}
```

then in your Main procedure, it would look like this:

```
Application.Run(appStartUp_);
if (appOK) {
  Application.Run(new Manager());
}
```