# C# - How to change the Startup form Programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Is it possible to change the startup form programmatically, because when my application starts it asks for the serial key and I want it to only show up ONCE and when the user enters the serial number and presses the continue button, it will check if the serial number is correct and take him to the main form.

But how is it possible to change the startup Form after the user enters serial number?

For example i want it to lead them to Form1 instead of TrialCheck.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 C#.

Comment: It would help to see what you are doing now.

Comment: @DonBitnott What do you exactly mean?

Comment: In your `Program.cs` file inside the `Main()` method, check if the user has already entered a valid serial number. If he does, load `Form1`, if not, load `TrialCheck`

Comment: @JoshPart It doesn't work for me to interact with other form's controls for example if i use:  static void Main()
        {
            if(TrialCheck.textBox1.Text == "SERIAL")
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new TrialCheck());
            }
            
            
        } it says I can't access it due to the protection level

Comment: See [C# Winforms Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42261329/719186).

Comment: How are you saving/storing when your user enters a valid serial number?

Comment: I actually don't.. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, that's another question. After your user succesfully enters a valid serial number, you should store it on a database, a file, or windows registry. Without storing it there's no way to know he/she already has entered a valid one once.

Answer (score 4):

Your project has a `Program.cs` file which is the entry point to your program.

In its `Main()` method you should perform your validation and then decide which form to load.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        bool registered = FunctionThatChecksSerialNumber();
        if (registered)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new TrialCheck());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I understood from OP's question that `TrialCheck` takes care of that